# What is the industry standard for securely sending encrypted files from a client to server over the internet?

Tags: security, encryption, go, network-protocols, file-transfer

I'm currently building a filesystem written in Go that sends files from a client to server, in encrypted format. I am very new to information transfer protocols.

I want to send information about the user (username, password hashed with bcrypt) to a server, which would then open a secure session of some type with the client where the server and client could send and receive file data and metadata. This should keep a backup of the client's files on the server, and encrypted with a symmetric key unique that is unique to that user (with AES256 or similar). I want all of this to happen as a background task, without input from the user aside from the user/pass at startup.

- What would be the best protocol to transfer (encrypted) files? TCP, SSH, SFTP, or something else?
- What about transferring metadata about files?
- What is the best way to authenticate a user before opening a session (for this case)? Using certificates or password hashes created from bcrypt?

Comment: Once the data is on the server, should the server be able to read the data? For example, should it be possible to view the stored data over secure web access, or should the data be kept private, even from the server admins?

Comment: I was thinking that the data would be kept private, even from the server admins.

Comment: Then maybe you want want `[go.crypto/openpgp](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.crypto/openpgp)` to encrypt files to a key the server admins don't have.

Comment: Hopefully stating the obvious: you should first open a secure connection, and then send information about the user over that secure connection, not the other way around. Servers (services?) should not "open a secure session" to a client.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [security](http://security.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 4):

SSL/TLS is standard. You would need to enable that with a valid certificate from a certificate authority on your domain i.e. `https` rather than `http`. Once you have the SSL connection established all communication will be encrypted preventing man-in-the-middle attacks. The standard way to authenticate a user is username/password or any variation of that type i.e. email/password. You can also you OAuth for authentication. Store the passwords as hashes on your server.

**Update:**

[This article discusses the importance of choosing the correct hashing algorithm.](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence) Common hashing algorithms such as `MD5` and `SHA1` are vulnerable to certain attacks and suffer from collisions. Much more cryptographically strong algorithms have been developed such as bcrypt.

Comment: OpenSSL is an implementation of SSL/TLS and a cryptographic library & command line application. It's not a standard.

Comment: Note that Oauth and OAuth2 are quite different from each other. Both provide authorisation functions but please be aware which you are dealing with if you go down that route.

Answer (score 2):

First off, don't roll your own encryption.  The easiest way to do what you're looking for would be to open a TLS connection over TCP (making sure to validate the server's certificate), do a password authentication (like you would to a web site), then send file metadata followed by the file contents.  TLS can also authenticate the client using a certificate if you prefer.